# Continuity of the distance from one dimensional subspaces in Banach spaces

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, normed-spaces, quotient-spaces

Let $X$ be a Banach space, call $S_X$ its unit sphere and let $x\in X$ be fixed. Is it true that the function $f:S_X\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ given by $y\mapsto\Vert x+\langle y\rangle\Vert$ (i.e. the distance of $x$ from the subspace spanned by $y$) is continuous? So far I only managed to prove its upper semicontinuity. If $\{y_n\} \subset S_X$ is a sequence of vectors converging to some $y\in S_X$, observe that for each $n$ and each scalar $t$ one has $\Vert x+\langle y_n\rangle\Vert\leq\Vert x-ty_n\Vert$. Passing to the limit on both sides one gets:
$$ \limsup_{n\to+\infty}\Vert x+\langle y_n\rangle\Vert\leq\Vert x-ty\Vert $$
Finally, taking the infimum on the right side over all scalars $t$ leads to the formula:
$$ \limsup_{n\to+\infty}\Vert x+\langle y_n\rangle\Vert\leq\Vert x+\langle y\rangle \Vert $$
Which proves the upper semicontinuity. What about lower semicontinuity? Any suggestion or help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fix a sequence $y_n \in S_X$ such that $y_n \to y$. First, by the reverse triangle inequality, we have that 
$$\|x + \lambda y_n\| - \|x+ \lambda y\| \leq |\lambda| \|y_n - y\|.$$
For fixed $\varepsilon > 0$ pick $\lambda_0$ such that $\|x + \lambda_0 y\| \leq \|x + \langle y \rangle \| + \frac{\varepsilon}{2}$. Then we get that
$$\|x + \langle y_n \rangle \| \leq \|x + \lambda_0 y_n \| \leq |\lambda_0| \|y_n - y\| + \|x + \lambda_0 y\| \leq  |\lambda_0| \|y_n - y\| + \|x + \langle y \rangle \| + \frac{\varepsilon}{2}$$
Then, for sufficiently large $n$, $\|y_n - y\| \leq \frac{\varepsilon}{2(1+|\lambda_0|)}$ and hence $\|x + \langle y_n \rangle \| - \|x + \langle y \rangle \| \leq \varepsilon$.

It remains to to see that for sufficiently large $n$, $\|x + \langle y \rangle \| - \|x + \langle y_n \rangle \| \leq \varepsilon$ also. This is where I will need the assumption that $\|y_n\|$ is bounded away from $0$.

Here, we pick a sequence $\lambda_n$ such that $\|x + \lambda_n y_n\| \leq \|x + \langle y_n \rangle \| + \frac{\varepsilon}{2}$. Since $y_n \in S_X$, we have that 
$$|\lambda_n| \leq \|x + \lambda_n y_n\| + \|x\| \leq \|x + \langle y_n \rangle \| + \frac{\varepsilon}{2} + \|x\| \leq \|x + y_n\| + \frac{\varepsilon}{2} + \|x\| \leq 1 + \frac{\varepsilon}{2} + 2\|x\|.$$

Hence $\lambda_n$ is a bounded sequence. The result now follows by the same technique as we used for the first case. Indeed, by the reverse triangle inequality, we have for $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$
$$\| x + \lambda y \| - \|x + \lambda y_n\| \leq |\lambda| \| y_n - y\|$$

As a result, we see that
$$\| x + \langle y \rangle \| \leq \|x + \lambda_n y\| \leq |\lambda_n| \|y_n - y\| + \|x + \lambda_n y_n\| \leq |\lambda_n| \|y_n - y\| + \|x + \langle y_n \rangle \| + \frac{\varepsilon}{2}$$

Now, since $\lambda_n$ is bounded, for sufficiently large $n$ we have that $|\lambda_n| \|y_n - y\| \leq \frac{\varepsilon}{2}$ and so $\| x + \langle y \rangle \| - \|x + \langle y_n \rangle\| \leq \varepsilon$.

In total, this proves that for sufficiently large $n$, $|\|x + \langle y \rangle\| - \|x + \langle y_n \rangle \|| \leq \varepsilon$ which is the desired result.

Comment: Nice. In the first part, you may have a division by zero if $0$ is an eligible value for $\lambda_0$. That's no problem with the standard interpretation of $\frac{\varepsilon}{2\lvert\lambda_0\rvert} = +\infty$ in that case, but if you have qualms about it you may as well use $\lVert y_n - y\rVert < \frac{\varepsilon}{2(1+\lvert\lambda_0\rvert)}$ for sufficiently large $n$. (Or posit $\lambda_0 \neq 0$, but that requires a short argument that that's always possible.)

Comment: @DanielFischer Well spotted, I edited to include your suggestion

Comment: Amazing. Thanks! Concerning the small issue in the first part pointed out by @DanielFischer: I believe the whole first part is unnecessary as I had already showed that the function is upper semicontinuous. The harder and more useful part was the second.

Comment: I also noticed that the proof doesn't make use of any completeness assumption and it can be assumed that $X$ is just a normed space.

Comment: @DavideR. Sure. I do think that including the first part does a couple of things though (and so will leave it there). First, it's good motivation for the second part, since I think the first part is the easy bound and is motivation to try to make the same technique work for the other part. Secondly, I think it would have been potentially confusing to try to combine a proof of one direction using $\lim\sup$ and another using $\varepsilon$-handling and so I wrote it this way to avoid having to do that.

Comment: @DavideR. Yes, you can assume that $X$ is a normed space and also you can replace $S_X$ with any set $S \subset X$ such $\operatorname{dist}(0,S) > 0$ by a minor adaptation of the proof that $\lambda_n$ is bounded given here.

Comment: Of course it's better to leave it there, having two ways of proving the same result is more insightful anyway! Thanks once more